# evaluate data from keithley 3706A with python script

Tags: python, measure, visa, pyvisa

I have a keithley 3706A meter and would like to evaluate the readings using my python script.

But I have the following errors:

1. I get any values regardless of whether voltage is present or not.
2. My second query command does not work

Does anyone have additional commands for the keithley 3706a to read out values?

```
instrument_rescource_string = "TCPIP0::10.49.119.153::inst0::INSTR"

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
keithley = rm.open_resource(instrument_rescource_string)
print(keithley)
if keithley.query('*IDN?'):
    print('Connection to Keithley 3706A .')
else:
    print('No Connection to Keithley 3706A.')
keithley.write_termination = '\n'
keithley.read_termination = '\n'
keithley.write('ROUT:SCAN (@101)',)
#response = keithley.write('ROUT:CLOSE (@101)')
value2= keithley.write('READ?')

#keithley.timeout = 25000

response = keithley.query('MEAS:VOLT:DC?')
#keithley.timeout = 'None'
print(response)
print(value2)


keithley.close()

tkFenster = Tk()

tab_parent = ttk.Notebook()
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab4 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)

tkFenster.title('ValDATA')
tkFenster.geometry('800x600')


Sheet = StringVar() 
Sheetname = Entry(tkFenster,textvariable = Sheet)
R_b = StringVar()
Messpunkte = StringVar()
R_bname = Entry(tkFenster,textvariable = R_b)
MP1 = Entry(tkFenster,textvariable = Messpunkte)

 MP1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

durchsuchen = Button(tkFenster,text ="Durchsuchen")

READ = Button(tkFenster,text ="Keitley Sync",command=Keityhley_Sync)

#READ.place(x=90,y=0)
DMC_lesen.grid(row = 1, column = 300)
Label(tkFenster, text ="Messpunkt 01:").grid(row=2)


Messung_Start = Button(tkFenster,text ="Messung Starten",command=Messung_Starten)
Messung_Start.grid(row = 3, column = 300)

Keithley_SETUP = Button(tkFenster,text ="Daten bilden",command= Setup)
Keithley_SETUP.grid(row = 4`your text`, column = 300)


tkFenster.mainloop()
```